# Wrong kerning after \beta on printout

Tags: printing, kerning

The following minimal example looks fine on my system:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\Huge Test $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ Test
\end{document}
```

The PDF looks like this:

[image]

But when I print it out, the text looks like this!

[image: Printout]

What happened to my `\beta`?

Comment: Looks like a font or printer driver issue to me. I don't think other people will be able to recreate this issue. Try printing from a different PDF viewer / PC / to a different printer for comparison.

Comment: The problem is only with `\beta`? Try `latex` and convert `dvi` to `ps` and then to `pdf`.

Comment: @Sigur `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` results in a working copy. What does this mean?

Comment: @MartinScharrer The problem persists on two different printers (both HP LaserJets) and printing (not creating) on two different machines.

Comment: as @MartinScharrer mentions, the pdf viewer you are using may be the issue? which one are you using and were your using the same one when your tried on a different machine?

Comment: @Hooked, try to print directly from the `ps` file.

Comment: @ArTourter it seems that `evince` may be the problem as it works with the `adobe`. This sounds like a bug with the pdf viewer and not LaTeX. Thanks for all the help! I'm going to vote to close as too localized, please help finish it off. I want to leave the post up so that someone else can come across it though.